# javascript scroll to bottom of div class

Tags: javascript, django, html

Hi I am trying to implement a simple chatbox in django and was wondering how to scroll to the bottom of a div class using javascript? Basically when the page loads I would like so that users can see the most recent message sent to them instead of the least recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this recently for a similar thing. I found a basic jquery plug-in that will smoothly scroll an element onto the screen.

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.scrollMinimal = function() {

    var cTop = this.offset().top;
    var cHeight = this.outerHeight(true);
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var visibleHeight = $(window).height();

    if (cTop < windowTop) {
      $('body').animate({'scrollTop': cTop}, 'slow', 'swing');
    } else if (cTop + cHeight > windowTop + visibleHeight) {
      $(jQuery.browser.webkit ? "body": "html")
        .animate({'scrollTop': cTop - visibleHeight + cHeight}, 'slow', 'swing');
    }
  };

}(jQuery));
```

which is used like this:

```
$('#chat').scrollMinimal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the basic script is set the scrollTop equal to scrollHeight, so you need a script like this:

```
var DIV = document.getElementById('theDIVElement');
DIV.scrollTop = DIV.scrollHeight;
```

You only need to change `theDIVElement` to your DIV id.

Comment: okay that's great! does that work for div classes too and not just id's?

Comment: @MarsJ Well, you just need to use `getElementsByClassName` function to localize the element. The essential part is the second line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I used in my chat:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
<!-- 
function myScroll() { 
    window.scrollBy(0,01) 
    setTimeout('myScroll()',100); } 
if (document.layers || document.all) 
    myScroll() 
//--></SCRIPT>
```

This is also nice for when new messages are added, if you scroll to the bottom too fast, it's hard on your eyes while you're trying to read.