# Scrolling programmatically to the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, ruby, scroll

I want to scroll to the bottom of the page programmatically using a Ruby script, since the webpage has implemented an infinite scroll. Can I do this with mechanize?

Comment: I don't know.... Can you? What have you tried?

Comment: I guest this ansewer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184453/javascript-scroll-to-bottom-of-div-class

Comment: Usually infinite scroll is implemented using AJAX calls that are triggered by scrolling.  If you post the url of the site you are trying to scrape, I might be able to tell you more.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use window.scrollBy() & window.scrollTo() , may be this will help

Answer (score 0):

The following code will scroll to the bottom, even if the document height is dynamic.

```
const getDocHeight = function() {
  return Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight,
    document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight,
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight,
    document.documentElement.clientHeight
  );
}; 

scrollToBottom = () => {
  let maxHeight = getDocHeight();

  window.scrollBy(0, maxHeight);

  window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if (getDocHeight() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = getDocHeight();

      window.scrollBy(0, maxHeight);
    }
  };
};

scrollToBottom();
```